# If the charge density is constant, then how can it be depend on distance?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, density

[image][image][image]

Imagine we have some constants like 1,2,3 etc. Then how can they be dependent on any other thing?

[image]

The same is the case with charge density: whether it be volume charge density, surface charge density, linear charge density.

We know that the charge is distributed uniformly all over the conductor - which means that every volume, area, and length carries an equal amount of charge and if the charge is the same and the volume, area or length we are taking is also the same then it means that $\frac{dQ}{dV},\frac{dQ}{A}$ and $\frac{dQ}{dL}$ is also same then if it is constant then how can it be depended on any other thing(distance)?

One more thing if a material carries a charge and its volume is fixed then $\frac{dQ}{dV}$ should be constant every time whatever the distance be. Then how does charge density depend on distance?

Comment: A constant function $f(x)=c$ that ignores its input position variable $x$ is still a sensible function to have. Please make it easier for people to read your question; it makes people not want to answer your question if you present it this way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My simple question is that if the charge is distributed uniformly over a conductor then how can the charge density be a function of distance and vary from one point to another??

Comment: What distance? You can, for example, propose that the total charge on some object changes as it travels. But the charge density on that object remains uniform. Here the distance would be the distance of the center of mass of the object from some reference point, not the distance to the particular location where the charge density is to be determined.

Comment: And my question is why is charge density a function of distance?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are simply misunderstanding the question. The question says

> a continuous charge distribution in space has a volume charge density $\rho$

You are interpreting that statement to mean that $\rho$ is a constant, but that is not stated in the question. The symbol $\rho$ could be a number or it could be a function of some variables that are understood in context. The context already gives a strong hint that $\rho$ is a function by the statement "distribution in space". However, if there were any doubt, it is clarified subsequently where it says

> the volume charge density $\rho$ is a function of $\vec r_i$

In context, it cannot be more clear that $\rho$ is a function, not a constant.

The author does not use the words "constant", "uniform", "same", or "fixed". Nor any other description of the sort that would indicate that $\rho$ does not change over time or position. Those descriptions are from you and are clearly not what is intended by the author.

Comment: I am not interpreting anything ….now listen to me carefully and then answer me ……..we know that charge is distributed uniformly over the conductor……so if we take the volume constant, then the charge density should be constant(as the charge distribution is uniform) ……so my question is if the charge per unit volume is same then how can charge debsity vary??

Comment: Actually i am in contradiction with this statement…Author is not saying that charge density is constant but if you have some common sense then you can assume that if charge distribution is uniform then charge density should be constant??

Comment: And if you have time then listen my question properly

Comment: And how does distribution in space mean that it is a function

Comment: @Physicsstudent said “we know that charge is distributed uniformly over the conductor”. This is false. I am not sure why you believe it. It is not generally true in physics and it is specifically not true in this question.

Comment: Oh my god….you opened my eyes…..but one question is still there that…………. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjnuJ7oorGAAxWPTGwGHcliADsQFnoECBkQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FWhy-are-surface-charges-in-a-conductor-uniformly-distributed%23%3A~%3Atext%3DIf%2520the%2520shape%2520of%2520conductor%2Cdistribution%2520to%2520be%2520non%252Duniform.&usg=AOvVaw2nMnCGsOCHKOUykwlx9sY8&opi=89978449………..as this link says that if shape is non uniform then charge distribution is non uniform but in the case of  a uniform shape will the charge density be constant???

Comment: You should post that as a new question. But take some time to formulate it clearly in your own words instead of just linking to the quora question

Comment: And see this link as well please and then please correct my knowledge…… https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwivi-_lo7GAAxXuRmwGHVEoD0MQFnoECBMQAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphysicsexperiments.eu%2F2120%2Fcharge-distribution-on-conductor-and-insulator%23%3A~%3Atext%3DIf%2520we%2520charge%2520a%2520conductor%2Cas%2520far%2520away%2520as%2520possible..&usg=AOvVaw3d9lrYrgXFvY4P2Pm5flkS&opi=89978449

Comment: This doesnt need a separate question plz correct me

Comment: @Dale in the case of an ideal conductor the (net) charge density must be 0, because there is no E field in an ideal conductor. 0 charge everywhere is a uniform distribution of charge. Of course there may be surface charges, and none of this applies to non-ideal conductors.

Answer (score 1):

> if the charge density is constant throughout the conductor then how can it be depended on distance??

The problem you posted doesn't say there is a conductor present.

Charge can be placed on non-conductive materials. This is how static charge typically builds up, for example when you rub a balloon on your hair.

There are also cases like when a space charge is built up by emission into a vacuum (as in certain kinds of vacuum tubes) where the charge is somewhat mobile, but its motion is slow enough that we can consider it as immobile when determining the electric field at some particular moment in time.

When you place a charge on or in a non-conductive material then it (typically) stays where you put it, so it's possible to set up whatever charge distribution you like, and its not necessary to assume the charge distribution is uniform.

Comment: But tell me that if it is a conductor then is this statement false??

Comment: And i want to know that if the material in which charge is flowing is a conductor then, will the charge density depend on distance…..and if it does then how??

Comment: @Physicsstudent, if it's an ideal conductor then the bulk of the material must be neutral because there is no E field, and therefore no field terminating in the material. But there is often a surface charge on a conductive body. Since the charge in the bulk is 0 at all points in the bulk, it does not depend on position.

Comment: @Dale is saying that charge will depend on distance, you are saying that it will not depend on distance …….can somebody tell me what the truth is??

Comment: @Physicsstudent, Dale doesn't say it "will" depend on distance. He says that in this problem it's explicitly stated that it does depend on distance. That isn't possible in an ideal conductor. In an insulator, or even a semiconductor, we can definitely create situations where charge density does depend on position.

Comment: @Physicsstudent, again there's no reason to believe that the person who wrote the problem in your book intended that the region under consideration should be a conductor of any kind.

Comment: So you mean that a conducting volume,length,surface……these all will have uniform charge density??

Comment: @Physicsstudent, Not only will it have a uniform charge density, the charge density will be 0. If there was non-zero charge, then there would be a gradient on the field due to that charge. But the E field in an ideal conductor is 0, meaning there can't be a gradient on the field. And therefore there can't be a net charge present.  (Again, there can be a surface charge)

Comment: Can you one more thing plz that will the “linear charge density” be constant everytime or not??

Comment: @Physicsstudent, how is linear charge density involved in this question? Normally we only talk about that when charge is concentrated in a 1-dimensional region. It wouldn't apply in the bulk of a conductive material. And it doesn't apply to the question you asked about, which specifies a volume charge density.

Comment: @Physicsstudent, really you should ask the question you want to get the answer to, instead of asking a question and expecting us to answer something you didn't ask.

Comment: See my question properly i have written in it…..dQ/dL as well

Comment: @Physicsstudent, is the line within the bulk of a conductor, or is the line, for example, along a conductive wire in space?

Comment: I am talking about a conductive wire in space…..see image in the question.

Comment: @Physicsstudent, in that case the surface charge on the wire is being approximated as a line charge, and you can not assume it is uniform without more information.

Comment: So is charge density non uniform in line charge?

Comment: My answer says that charge density is 0 (and therefore uniform) in the bulk of a conductor. The example of a wire in space is not about the bulk of a conductor. The "in space" part is more important than the wire part. This example is not relevant to the main thrust of your question about charge "in a conductor".

Comment: Can you please tell me how can the charge distribution be non uniform in case of a wire (conductor) carrying charge …….see the image which i attached and then answer me

Comment: @Physicsstudent, as shown in the image, imagine the wire is bent in an irregular shape. Below the wire there is a ground plane. Now apply a voltage between the wire and the ground plane. The parts of the wire that happen to be closer to the plane have more capacitance and the parts that are farther away have less. Therefore in order for the wire to be an equipotential region (which it is, because it's a conductor) there must be charge concentrated in the parts of the wire closer to the plane, and less charge (per unit length) in the parts of the wire further from the plane.